# jquery Color darkening code returning 4 digit hex codes

Tags: jquery

i made some come code to dynamically make the box shadow of buttons a darker version of their background colors, but sometimes it returns a 4 digit hex code which doesn't work.
Can you guys tell me what's wrong with the code?

It happens with for example #0fe93b

```
function rgb2hex(rgb){
rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
return "#" + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2);}

function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt) {
var usePound = false;
if (col[0] == "#") {
    col = col.slice(1);
    usePound = true;
}
var num = parseInt(col,16);
var r = (num >> 16) + amt;
if (r > 255) r = 255;
else if  (r < 0) r = 0;
var b = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt;
if (b > 255) b = 255;
else if  (b < 0) b = 0;
var g = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;
if (g > 255) g = 255;
else if (g < 0) g = 0;
return (usePound?"#":"") + (g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16);}

$("input[type=submit]").each(function() {
//get button color
var btnclr = $(this).css("background-color");
//make darker
$(this).css({"box-shadow": "0 -3px 20px " + LightenDarkenColor(rgb2hex(btnclr), -80) + " inset"});
});
```

Comment: `0 << 8` becomes `0`, but you need two digits per color (ie `00`), I would recommend a left-padding function

Comment: @Shameen what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example returns only 4 digits because red and blue both become `0`, without 'padding' it to two digits per colour. (Expected: `"#009900"`, Actual: `"#9900"`)

You also had some colors labelled wrong, it should be red, green, blue.

Here is the updated `LightenDarkenColor` function (with an extra function to pad zeroes):

```
function padZero(str, n) {
    str = str.toString()
    while (str.length < n) {
        str = "0" + str;
    }
    return str;
}

function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt) {
    var usePound = false;
    if (col[0] == "#") {
        col = col.slice(1);
        usePound = true;
    }
    var num = parseInt(col,16);

    var r = (num >> 16) + amt;
    if (r > 255) r = 255; else if (r < 0) r = 0;

    var g = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt;
    if (g > 255) g = 255; else if (g < 0) g = 0;

    var b = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;
    if (b > 255) b = 255; else if (b < 0) b = 0;

    return (usePound?"#":"") + padZero(r.toString(16), 2) + padZero(g.toString(16), 2) + padZero(b.toString(16), 2);
}
```

Now when you run `LightenDarkenColor("#0fe93b",-80)` it returns `"#009900"`